# Breusch-Pagan_test in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I am trying to run the Breusch-Pagan test in python 3 using the below code. It works perfectly in python 2.7, but when I run it in Anaconda with python 3.6 instead, I get the following the error: "module 'statsmodels.stats.api' has no attribute 'het_breuschpagan'".

I have looked at the statsmodel documentation at this link, https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan.html, and know that I am running the right code.

`import statsmodels.stats.api as sms`

`breuschpagan_test = sms.het_breuschpagan(model_run.resid, model.model.exog)`

Does anyone know a solution to this or a different way to call this statsmodel function in python 3?

Also, due to limitations at work, I cannot uninstall/re-install or update my statsmodel library at the moment either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running an old version of statsmodels on python 3.6? Earlier versions had the name misspelled as `het_breushpagan`   (missing c in sch). Or check what functions are available in `statsmodels.stats.diagnostic`.

Comment: @Josef That worked! Thank you!!